# Spring Dynamic service provider injection based on configuration in properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple mutually exclusive data sources and I want to configure which implementation to inject/autowire into Controller based on a property defined in a configuration file.

I'm thinking of something along the lines @Qualifier but I'm no spring expert so can't figure the mechanics.

The aim is to avoid the convoluted if/else that will result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the trick with `context:property-placeholder` and `@Qualifier`.

It will look like the following:

**app.properties**

```
some.implementation=com.example.MyServiceImpl
```

**spring context file**

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:/app.properties"/>

<bean id="myService" class="${some.implementation}" />
```

**Controller**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myService")
private MyService myService;
```

As the opposite solution: you can save in properties file bean ID, and use it within `@Qualifier`

```
@Qualifier("${some.implementation.bean.id}")
```

But if you are using Spring 3.1+, then you probably need to look at [Profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much. The profiles feature looks good especially since i will have a number of classes doing this dynamic behaviour and we are using 3.1.2.RELEASE. will explore both  Tx